# Android - Why would activity context suddenly be null on one device type

Tags: android, null, android-context

I've been working on an app that suddenly wont work on my droid x2 test device but works just fine on everything else. I've tried turning on and off the phone, deleting the existing copy of the app and reinstalling, and finally I actually went and did a factory reset but for what ever reason when the main activity goes to instantiate the context that I use is coming up null how ever its only doing this on one device and no others.

I went through and checked my manifest flags and I'm pretty sure that's not it.

When I debugged and stepped through the application I noticed that from `oncreate` it goes strait to `onResume` and where I use the context for a method it comes up null but only when I run it on the droid x2. It wont do that on any other device.

The strangest thing is that this never happened before today and I haven't made any changes to the code in about 3 days. In fact its only been a problem for the past couple of hours.

here's the logcat when it fails:

```
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {graffit.main/graffit.main.MyView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2228)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1721)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at graffit.main.MyView.onResume(MyView.java:728)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3912)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2191)
02-20 19:30:12.354: E/AndroidRuntime(21483):    ... 12 more
```

The crash happens when I log in and the MyView activity is supposed to open but the context is null. I know that because I debugged and at this method in my code where I use the context I see its null.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try{
    System.gc();
    myContext.startGpsListener();
    //Log.w("curLoc is from"+myContext.curLoc.getProvider(),"thats it");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("UID")){
        curr_uid = getIntent().getStringExtra("UID");
        curr_rid = getIntent().getStringExtra("RID");
        curr_profimg = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagepath");
        curr_usrname = getIntent().getStringExtra("UsrName");
        myContext.setUserInfo(curr_uid, curr_usrname);<-------------failure here
    }
```

Comment: I guess I should explain that....I use an extended custom context that holds other information. It works fine on the device right now but for the past 4 hours it was broken for some reason and the context wouldnt hold anything. But just like magic it started working again. I tried re instantiating it in my onresume where it failed but It wouldnt even hold context there either. It was just one of those weird phantom errors I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where are you initializing `myContext`? since you are in activity, call startGpsListener(); directly and if possible,  call System.gc() as the last statement in method

Comment: Yeah Ill try to use that just to make sure nothing is getting cleaned up to early in my onresume.

Comment: Where you call `System.gc()` doesn't matter here. Anything that can be referenced through a strong reference can not be GCed so it surely has nothing to do with your problem. Why do you even call System.gc() in the first place? It is very rare one should be concerned of actually forcing a GC to happen unless your application is a real-time game and you want to minimize the change of the small lag caused by GC to occur at an inconvenient time. If your running out of memory you can bet your ass GC will happen before OutOfMemoryException will be thrown whether or not you explicitly asked for it.

Answer (score 0):

SO BIZARRE....without any changes to my code the application finally started working again. Could have been some Verizon spy ware running in the background interfering with my app.

Comment: since it started working, might be in future it stop again, so handle this problem so that you code didnt get affected.

Comment: Yeah Im looking into it but its one of those phantom bugs that I think certain devices may just run into. It couldve been related to the debugger and running it from eclipse as well.